# I get responsiveness issue only with my mobile

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design

My react application has a responsiveness issue that  only occurs on my phone, which is a Galaxy J7 Pro with a resolution of 510 pixels wide.

I've tested the app in a browser and it works perfectly in this width.
I've tried it on my tablet and my other phone and it works fine.

However, when I test it with the J7 Pro, I get responsiveness issues.

[screenshot from j7pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcmLI.jpg)

[screenshot from my other phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cN2v.jpg)

[screenshot from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDyPi.png)

Comment: From the information provided, impossible to tell what is causing the situation. But, to assist in debugging it: is the mobile issue browser-related?

Comment: @Darcy Yes, I use the Chrome browser on my phone but the problem appears even when I use the Samsung browser as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tunnel to test the responsiveness on your actual phone and make changes as needed. One example is `ngrok` if you are on `localhost:3000` you can simply do:

```
ngrok http 3000
```

It will give you a link that you can visit on your phone. And make necessary changes to make it responsive.

installation: https://ngrok.com/download

docs: https://ngrok.com/docs